# Kernel died, restarting while fitting SVM model in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have written a program in python which is predicting locality name based on train data but same program work for small dataset but now I am tryting with large dataset but getting error `Kernel died, restarting`.

I am importing data from SQl server.

while run this like kernel will died `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`:

Program:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
#pipeline of feature engineering and model

from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, make_pipeline

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

word_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
features = FeatureUnion([('words', word_vectorizer), ])

kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), method='sigmoid', cv=kf)

model = make_pipeline(features, calibrated_svc)

print("Model Created Successfully...")


model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Data fitted Successfully...")
```

After running model.fit(X_train, y_train)

getting error: `An error ocurred while starting the kernel
b''`

I have updated all libraries, reinstalled conda aswell, installed mkl also but same error.

Please suggest to solve error

Comment: a common issue for this is actually running out of RAM. Check how much ram your program shoots up to before kernel dies. If that is the issue, you need to figure out a better way to read your entire data.

Comment: I just checked memory uses is only 47%.